# Codeigniter - process a retrieved values from DB before sending them into a view

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter-2

I want to display a timestamp value catched from DB by using a php function `date()` to properly format my date time.

But the question is - could it be done before passing it to the view file ? 
I want to keep my view file as clean as possible concerning php functions inside a view file.

Retrieved items from a database by using `/models/content_model.php`:

```
function getPages($per_page){
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
    $query = $this->db->get('content', $per_page, $this->uri->segment(3));
    return $query->result();
}
```

Then, it's processed by controller `/controllers/content.php`:

```
...
// Get data
$componentData['results'] = $this->content_model->getPages(5);
...
```

And displaying results in `views/content/home.php`:

```
<?php
    <?php foreach($results as $item):?>
        echo $item->date_created;
     <?php endforeach;?>
?>
```

Will output a date (type timestamp in DB) something like this: `2011-08-14 18:34:04`

Instead of using a `date()` function inside of a view file `views/content/home.php`, i want to process it through `date()` function outside of the view, not sure if it should be done in model or controller.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in controller class. At first make a private function name DateProcess and send the query result and process the date as you want. Then you can send the process data to view  file.

Comment: omg, i am really a big noob in programmation, can't get it. My `$componentData['results']` contains an array of retrieved items. I made a function `dateProcess($date)` which process a date, but how can i mix it with already retrieved results in array `$componentData['results']`. Thanks